# mem_fun and bind1st problem

Tags: c++, transform, mem-fun

I've following class:

```
class A {
public:
// ctr and etc ...
A*   clone(B* container);
};
```

Now, I've a `vector<A*> availableObjs` populated already. I want to call `clone` on each of those, so and insert cloned objects into a new container `clonedObjs` of type `vector<A*>`. I'm trying following - but it doesn't compile:

```
transform(availableObjs.begin(), availableObjs.end(), back_inserter(clonedObjs),
    bind1st(mem_fun(&A::clone), container)); // container is of type B*
```

Is there a easy way out? I've a lot classed like A - so making each of those a functor is too much task.

Comment: Are you sure you want to have pointers in your container? You must not call any modifying algorithm on that algorithm (like for example sort). However, you could use a vector of shared_ptr<A*>, then you support value semantics again.

Answer (score 12):

You need to use `bind2nd` instead of `bind1st`:

```
transform(availableObjs.begin(), availableObjs.end(), back_inserter(clonedObjs),
    bind2nd(mem_fun(&A::clone), container)); // container is of type B*
```

The functor created by `mem_fun(&A::clone)` expects an `A*` as its first parameter. This is the normally implicitly specified instance on which the method is called. The first "real" parameter of `A::clone` is the second parameter of `mem_fun(&A::clone)` and therefore needs to be bound with `bind2nd`.

Answer (score 2):

If you use Boost.Bind it might look like this:

```
std::transform(
               availableObjs.begin(), availableObjs.end(), 
               back_inserter(clonedObjs),
               boost::bind<A*>(boost::mem_fn(&A::clone), _1, container) );
```