# Can UnaryOperator be a member function when std::transform is called

Tags: c++, stl

Based on [std::transform](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/transform/)

```
template < class InputIterator, class OutputIterator, class UnaryOperator >
  OutputIterator transform ( InputIterator first1, InputIterator last1,
                             OutputIterator result, UnaryOperator op );
```

Can `op` be a member function? If so, how do I call it?

Comment: See [Boost.Bind](http://www.boost.org/libs/bind/).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762781/mem-fun-and-bind1st-problem

Comment: You question is slightly ambiguous. What class are you hoping to make `op` a member of? The class of `*first1`, the class of `*result`, the class of `*this`, or some other class?

Comment: @Rob, it is best if I know both cases.

Comment: @q0987 - see my answer. It describes the case of `op` being a member of the class of `*first1` and the case of `op` being a member of `*this`. You should be able to generalize from there.

Answer (score 4):

No (well, not directly). You need to use an adaptor, either old `std::mem_fun` (together with `bind1st`, IIRC) or `std::bind`/`boost::bind`.

```
std::transform(
    xs.begin(), xs.end(), ys.begin(),
    std::bind(&Class::member, &class_instance)
);
```

Comment: Isn't `class_instance` supposed to be supplied by `std::transform`?  So `std::mem_fun` by itself would probably be more appropriate than `bind1st`.

Comment: Replace `&class_instance` with `std::placeholders::_1`.

Comment: @Ben: `mem_fn` is the appropriate Boost/C++11 version.

Comment: @BenVoigt: No idea, OP can be about either, really.

Comment: IIRC C++11 deprecated `std::mem_fun()`.

Comment: I really envy all you folks here on StackOverflow who're able to use the fancy new C++11 features in their projects, are you all students or hobbyists? If you can use this stuff in your daytime job, please let me know where you work. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

It is pretty easy to do if you wrap the call in lambda:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

class C {
public:
  int op() const { return 1; }
};

class D {
  int op() { return 1; }
  void f() {
    std::vector<C> xs;
    std::vector<int> ys;
    std::transform(xs.begin(), xs.end(), ys.begin(),
      [](const C& x) { return x.op(); });
    std::transform(xs.begin(), xs.end(), ys.begin(),
      [this](const C& x) { return this->op(); });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a helper object, like [`std::less`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/less.html) but for a unary operator.

C++11 lambdas make this incredibly easy:

```
std::transform(xs.begin(), xs.end(), ys.begin(), [](the_type x){ return -x; });
std::transform(xs.begin(), xs.end(), ys.begin(), [](the_type x){ return !x; });
std::transform(xs.begin(), xs.end(), ys.begin(), [](the_type x){ return ~x; });
```

Or, use these flexible helpers:

```
struct negate
{
    template<typename T>
    auto operator()(const T& x) const -> decltype(-x) { return -x; }
};

struct invert
{
    template<typename T>
    auto operator()(const T& x) const -> decltype(!x) { return !x; }
};

struct complement
{
    template<typename T>
    auto operator()(const T& x) const -> decltype(~x) { return ~x; }
};

std::transform(xs.begin(), xs.end(), ys.begin(), negate());
std::transform(xs.begin(), xs.end(), ys.begin(), invert());
std::transform(xs.begin(), xs.end(), ys.begin(), complement());
```

Comment: @q0987: I showed examples of lambdas.  Was something wrong with them?